# switched branch and changes carried over

Tags: git

Originally I was on staging branch, and I had created a new branch called pdftest:

```
git checkout -b pdftest
```

I changed two files. I wanted to return to staging branch without those modifications carrying over:

```
$ git checkout staging
M   .ruby-gemset
M   .versions.conf
```

But the modifications carried over and those two files are now changed in staging branch as well. How could I have prevented the changes carrying over to staging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `git stash` and after you're done with your changes on staging, `git stash apply`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: I run git stash apply on staging or on the other branch?

Comment: You can run it on the branch that you'd like to have your stashed changes, which means any branch in the same repo. Stash temporarily stores your changes and can be applied to any branch you want in the same repository